# Swift type cast of float to float gives nil

Tags: swift, casting

I am trying to cast a number read from a JSON file as a float. The number is 0.35 but when I try to use an `as?` cast to a float it gives nil. Here is the code:

```
let maxHeight = biome["Max Height"] as? Float
print(biome["Max Height"]) // Prints '0.35'
print(maxHeight) // Prints 'nil'
```

The `biome` dictionary was previously casted as `[String:Any]`, and that is the only thing I can see having an affect on it. I have no idea why it returns nil as 0.35 should be a valid float.

I was expecting that it would just cast to a float since it is a float but this is not what happened.

Comment: What does the following show: `print(type(of: biome["Max Height"]))` ?

Comment: Shows Optional<Any>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON parsing of a floating point number will result in a value of type `Double`, not `Float`.

Using:

```
let maxHeight = biome["Max Height"] as? Double
```

will give you the expected value. If you really want a value of type `Float` then you can do something like:

```
if let val = biome["Max Height"] as? Double {
    let maxHeight = Float(val)
    // do stuff with maxHeight
}
```

---

You should consider changing how you parse the JSON so it gets converted into a proper `struct` with appropriate properties of the desired types instead of ending up with a dictionary of type `[String: Any]`. Look into using `Codable` and `JSONDecoder`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I assumed it was something wrong with what the JSON casted it as because Integers were always fine. 

On the topic of using Codable, I was going to do that but I opted for .jsonObject because I want the JSON files to be very moddable, similar to raws in Dwarf Fortress. This file contains data for biomes and I want users to be able to remove or add stuff. Every biome has certain properties so I think I can bundle those in a codable class and then bundle the additional functionality in some sort of tags system.